# Is it possible to select multiple declared ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

As above,assuming I have declared rng1, rng2 rng3 etc.is it possible to select the declared ranges in 1 selection? If so please can you provide the code?

Thanks

Comment: In an attempt to match the level of detail offered in your original post, look at `Union`

Comment: Can you please put some more context to your question? Are the declared ranges static or referred specifically in your code? Can you provide what code you have so far? A good place to start is to do a "Record Macro", select numerous ranges and start analyzing what works for your intentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky one, but if you record a macro you will see that the format is something like:

```
Range("A1:A10,C1:C10").Select
```

To change this over to a variable (which is the only way I can figure out how to do it):

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("C1:C10")

    Range(rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address).Select
End Sub
```

**UPDATED** As suggested by @user-somenumber- above that apparently was able to perfectly understand your question, but was too bothered by its brevity to post anything more than a hint, the `UNION` method works well here:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range

    Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("C1:C10")

    Union(rng1, rng2).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have three named ranges (rnge1, rnge2, rnge3), you can select all of them in vba like this:

```
Range("rnge1,rnge2,rnge3").Select
```

Comment: If the ranges are Named Ranges from the excel UI, then this will work. If the Ranges OP is speaking of are Declared variables within VBA, then this will not work. If you remove the quotes around them (because they are proper variables), it will run, but it will also select all of the cells between these ranges, essentially expanding it into one large range.